# Get the results from pbcopy to transform them to an array with applescript?

Tags: applescript

I have the following code to read contents from a file to open multiple Safari browsers.

```
set locations to paragraphs of (read (choose file with prompt "Pick text file containing urls"))
repeat with aLocation in locations
    tell application "Safari" to open location aLocation
end repeat
```

How can I read contents from pbcopy (copied result from Command-C action)? I tried as follows, but I couldn't get the lines, but the alphabets.

```
try
    set the locations to Unicode text of (the clipboard as record)
on error errMsg
    display dialog errMsg
end try
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the clipboard contains text whose lines are URLs, you can retrieve those URLs by using the following script:

```
set locations to paragraphs of (the clipboard as Unicode text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing to do is to make a bash script that will invoke `pbpaste` then use `osascript -e` to execute applescript within.